# match string inside quotes having at-least 1 uppercase char

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, pattern-matching

i have some string lines in my java files and trying to do an Eclipse Regex search but its not working. i want to highlight lines which have an Uppercase character in the string after **RequestParam(value =**
so from below 3 lines, only middle one should match ie
    ***RequestParam(value = "someNumber")*** which has uppercase 'N' in it.

```
public Response searchA(@RequestParam(value = "_s", required = true) String searchExpression,
public Response getNumber(@RequestParam(value = "someNumber", required = true) String agencyNumber,
public Response getStuff(@PathVariable("id") String asnId, @RequestParam(value = "customerid") String customerId,
```

i formed a regex expression and it seems to work on regex101 but not in eclipse.
https://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in Eclipse search:

```
RequestParam *\( *value *= *"[^"\nA-Z]*[A-Z][^"\n]*"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/17)

Make sure `case sensitive` and `regex` checkboxes are checked in Eclipse search.

Comment: it works but can you explain this regex. seems more complex than i anticipated.

Comment: Actually it is not complex. Most of the `<space>*` is there to match 0 or more spaces. `"[^"\nA-Z]*` matches a quote and then 0 or more of any character except uppercase letter or quote. `[A-Z]` matches uppercase letter. `[^"\n]*` matches anything but a quote followed by a quote. My demo link also has some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your regex in eclipse. It works correct way if checkboxes "case sensetive" and "regular expression" enabled in find dialog